# Blocking characters from PHP search script string

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP search script that gets results based on tags assigned in a MySQL database. I would like to block certain things from the query string. For example **!** or **,** or **a**

**How could I do this?** I hope people can understand my question.

My current code is:

```
if(!empty($_GET['q'])){
$keywords=explode(' ',$_GET['q']);
foreach($keywords as $query){
$query=mysql_real_escape_string($query);
$likes[]="keywords LIKE '%{$query}%'";
}

$searchResult=mysql_query("select * from questions where ".implode('or ',$likes)."limit 1");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($searchResult)){
    $results="<div class='webresult'>{$row['result']}</div>";
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. Can you make an example what you want to block?

Comment: Do you have a reasonable explanation, **why** do you want to strip out some certain characters? May be you are trying to solve another problem wrong way?

Comment: This looks like a job for MySQL's FULL TEXT search. Google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I thought - you are trying to solve another problem wrong way.

if you don't want to look for the *short* words - do so:

```
if(!empty($_GET['q'])){
  $keywords=explode(' ',$_GET['q']);
  foreach($keywords as $query){
    if (strlen($query) < 3) {
      $query=mysql_real_escape_string($query);
      $likes[]="keywords LIKE '%{$query}%'";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that's just silly mistake in my code. I am sure you can spot it yourself

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all characters you don't want with

```
$query = str_replace("!", "", $query);
$query = str_replace(",", "", $query);
$query = str_replace(".", "", $query);
```

and that with all characters you want to block

Comment: What do you mean by "when it's on its own"?

Comment: Then you could use `$query = str_replace(" a ", "", $query);`... But of course thats not the right way, better use ereg_replace instead; http://php.net/manual/de/function.ereg-replace.php

Comment: * Sry, you have to put that before the foreach and before that `$keywords=explode(' ',$_GET['q']);`. So you could change it to:
`$text = $_GET["q"]; $text = str_replace('!', '', $text); ... $keywords = explode(' ', $text);`

Comment: @DRP96 Actually, `ereg_replace` is deprecated. You want `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is certain words or characters you want to strip out, the easiest way to do it would be to store an array of those words or characters and use str_replace on the string before you explode.

```
$exclude = array("!","a","foo");
$clean = str_replace($exclude,"",$_GET['q']);
```

Then you can continue with your current code using the clean string:

```
$keywords=explode(' ',$clean);
```